# Как узнать id view в AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть несколько AutoCompleteTextView. И класс в котором они находятся реализует интерфейс AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.Вешаем на каждый AutoCompleteTextView слушатель:

```
    public class FragmentCreatContact extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
ContractGeo.ViewGeo{

    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCountri;
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoRegion;
    private ContractGeo.PresenterGeo1 presenterGeo1;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAutoCompleteAdapterCountri;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAutoCompleteAdapterRegion;
    private NewContactData contactData;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_created_contact,container);
       contactData=new NewContactData();

       presenterGeo1=new PresenterGeo();
       presenterGeo1.initView(this);

       autoCountri=(AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewCreateDialogCountri);
       autoCountri.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       autoCountriTextWatcher();

       autoRegion=(AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextRegion);
       autoRegion.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       autoRegionTextWatcher();
```

Вопрос вот в чем, можно ли в методе onItemClick узнать id AutoCompleteTextView:

```
  @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    switch (ВОТ ТУТ МНЕ НАДО УЗНАТЬ ID AutoCompleteTextView НО КАК??){
        case R.id.autoCompleteTextViewCreateDialogCountri:
            contactData.setCountriId(presenterGeo1.getNewData().get(position).getCountriId());
            break;
        case R.id.autoCompleteTextRegion:
            contactData.setRegionId(presenterGeo1.getNewData().get(position).getRegionId());
            break;
    }

}
```

На данный момент на каждый AutoCompleteTextView повесил отдельный лушатель, но получается громоздко, ведь будут еще AutoCompleteTextView.

```
 autoCountri=(AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewCreateDialogCountri);
   autoCountri.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           contactData.setCountriId(presenterGeo1.getNewData().get(position).getCountriId());
       }
   });
```

Comment: `parent.getId()`

Comment: @woesss parent.getId() и parent.getRootView().getId -  дают значение -1.

Comment: Я конечно не знаю, но position что дает?

Comment: @danilshik position это позиция выбранного пункта в адаптере.view.getId возвращает id view из адаптера.

Comment: М-да, действительно, в метод приходят вьюхи из попапа. На en-SO есть такой костыль: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41657988. В развитие этого костыля можно расширить адаптер, чтобы он содержал нужную информацию.